# Need to optimize the query and rewrite it as it taking a lot of time on running on server

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I have this query and taking so much time to run , is there any way i can improve it , with creating any new views ,,, i can`t create temp db tables as they are avoid by DBA because of load on server

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.email AS eml_addr,
    UPPER(max(FORMAT(cl.clicktime, 'dd-MMM-yyyy'))) AS lst_clk_mnth,
    UPPER(max(FORMAT(o.opentime, 'dd-MMM-yyyy'))) AS lst_opn_mnth
FROM [open] o WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN view_mailing m WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON (o.mailingid = m.mailingid)
INNER JOIN view_campaign c WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON (c.campaignid = m.campaignid)
LEFT JOIN click cl WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON (
            o.mailingid = cl.mailingid
            AND o.email = cl.email
            )
WHERE c.clientid IN (
        SELECT clientid
        FROM client
        WHERE sameclient IN (
                SELECT sameclient
                FROM client
                WHERE clientid IN (219)
                )
        )
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), cast(o.opentime AS DATETIME), 112) & gt;= 20130826
GROUP BY o.email;
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the purpose of both distinct and group by?

Comment: there is some duplicate data i guess , so i am trying to use distinct for that and group by is for email fields cause i need every thing according to it

Comment: and i both above views , i have clustered index ,,, so i guess thats the problem ... please advice .... they are taking 35 and 36 % cost

Comment: No there is not duplicate data.  group by o.email will produce unique values so there can be no duplicate rows

Comment: ok blam thanks ,,, i will take it out ..... but any other suggestion

Comment: Do you consider an answer a suggestion

Comment: no i am not . i already took distinct off . just asking if you can tell any other change that i can do on this query so runs perfect

Comment: So you don't consider a posted answer a suggestion?

Comment: i dont take it as suggestion .... i take it as solution and i change every thing  according to answers here and then test it ....

Comment: and yes offcourse i add few things from my knowledge and expireance too

Comment: English is not your first language? I suggest you try my posted answer.  Any suggestion I have will be in the answer.

Comment: oh sorry for the confusion , the solution you posted below, i thought its code from my question , thats y i was wondering where is solution posted ... i got it now ..... thanks for your help ..... really appriciate ....... again sorry for confussion ........................ and i was born and raised in england so guess know a little bit english hahahahahahah .......

Comment: Blam , and your solution is really a big help ..... thanks .....

Comment: If that answers your question then you can indicate so by giving it a check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the purpose of both a distinct and group by
A derived table does not use indexes
Date in a varchar is not optimal

```
SELECT o.email AS eml_addr,
       UPPER(max(FORMAT(cl.clicktime, 'dd-MMM-yyyy'))) AS lst_clk_mnth,
       UPPER(max(FORMAT(o.opentime,   'dd-MMM-yyyy'))) AS lst_opn_mnth
  FROM [open] o WITH (NOLOCK)  
  LEFT JOIN click cl WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON o.mailingid = cl.mailingid
   AND o.email = cl.email         
  JOIN view_mailing m WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON o.mailingid = m.mailingid   
  JOIN view_campaign c WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON c.campaignid = m.campaignid
  join client with (NOLOCK) 
    on c.clientid = client.sameclient 
   and client.clientid IN (219) 
 WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), cast(o.opentime AS DATETIME), 112) & gt;= 20130826
 GROUP BY o.email;
```

Comment: What a nice aligment! :)